# Trouble putting text on a new page after a table

Tags: tables, page-breaking

I have several large tables in my thesis that I want to isolate on a page by themselves as only two lines of text can fit underneath them. I have tried the `\newpage` and the `\pagebreak` commands, even trying to force it using `\pagebreak[4]`. However, LaTeX still puts text under the tables. It does not come up with an error when the document runs, it just doesn't seem to pay attention to the command. Does anyone know perhaps why or if there is a different way of doing this? I have read the other questions on the site but the two commands all seem to work for those problems!
Thanks in advance for any help.
Holly

Comment: use `[p]` then the tables are restricted to float pages.

Comment: normally latex will not put a small amount of text under a float (by default the text has to be at least 20% of the page) (as always it is very hard to suggest changes to code that we can't see.....)

Comment: Putting p in the float environment worked. I knew it had to be something simple. Thank you very much David

Comment: were you using `!` before? (hard to see how you can get just one or two lines otherwise)

Comment: I was using `[!h]` as I wanted three tables all on adjacent pages. Using `[p]` has put a couple of pages of text in between the tables but I am sure I can figure out a way of getting them all together. Thanks again!

Comment: `h` on its own is an error waiting to happen, and `!` means ignore all the typographic parameters like `\textfraction` that try to enforce good taste and just stick it there anyway.  You get what you ask for.....

Comment: `\clearpage` will flush all pending floats and stop them drifting off.

Comment: Perfect, `\clearpage` worked perfectly - all three tables are now on adjacent pages. Thanks for your help with that too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
\begin{table}[p]
```

then the tables are restricted to float pages and no text will be under them.

Note however that by default latex will not put text under a float unless at least 20% of the page has text. This is the parameter `\textfraction` which by default (and in `article class`) is set at 0.2.